# How to show all images in WooCommerce product description

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I want to replace my product description by my description + all product images (include variation product images) in single product page.

I can do that with Magento but now when change to Woocommerce I can not.

After research I tried with filter hook but not success.

I can add text to product decscription but I am stucking how to using functions `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` or `wp_get_attachment_image()`.

Sample code for display image as I know:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), array('700', '600'), "", array( "class" => "img-responsive" ) ).
```

How to apply in my code?

```
    // Display description tab when empty
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'display_description_product_tabs' );
        function display_description_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

        $tabs['description'] = array(
            'title'    => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 10,
            'callback' => 'woocommerce_product_description_tab',
        );

        return $tabs;
    }

    // Add image to description
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_product_image_woocommerce_description' );
    function add_product_image_woocommerce_description( $content ) {
        global $product;

        // Single product pages (woocommerce)
        if ( is_product() ) {

            // Image id
            $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

            $image_content = "";
            foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {

                $image_content .= '<img src="'. wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, 'full') . '" alt="image_content" width="500" height="600">';

            }

            $image_content .= '<p> TEST Image content </p>';

            // Inserting the custom content at the end
            $content .= $image_content;
        }

        return $content;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WC_Product` `get_image()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1842-L1866) like:

```
echo $product->get_image( array('700', '600'), array( "class" => "img-responsive" ), '' );
```

Then in your code you can buffer all echoed custom code plus the main product image *(at the end of your product description content)* as follow:

```
// Display description tab when empty
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'display_description_product_tabs' );
    function display_description_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['description'] = array(
        'title'    => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority' => 10,
        'callback' => 'woocommerce_product_description_tab',
    );

    return $tabs;
}

// Add image to description
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_product_image_woocommerce_description' );
function add_product_image_woocommerce_description( $content ) {
    global $product;

    // Single product pages (woocommerce)
    if ( is_product() ) {

        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        // HERE your main image
        echo $product->get_image( array('700', '600'), array( "class" => "img-responsive" ), '' );

        $image_content = "";

        // Loop through gallery Image Ids
        foreach( $product->get_gallery_image_ids() as $image_id ) {

            echo '<img src="'. wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'full') . '" alt="image_content" width="500" height="600">';
        }

        echo '<p> TEST Image content </p>'; // Testing text

        // Inserting the buffered content after
        $content .= ob_get_clean();
    }

    return $content;
}
```