# Display a second WooCommerce image from product gallery on the loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, woocommerce

i'm using this code to display woocommerce thumb:

```
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>

<img src="<?php  echo $image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
```

But looking solution how to display second image from product gallery. How to modify this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** The following will display a second image from product gallery *(first image)*:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>

<img src="<?php  echo $image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">

<?php
// Get gallery images IDs
if( $gallery_image_ids = get_post_meta( $loop->post->ID, '_product_image_gallery', true ) ) :
    // Convert a coma separated string of Ids to an array of Ids
    $gallery_image_ids = explode(',', $gallery_image_ids);

    // Display the first image (optional)
    ?><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( reset($gallery_image_ids), 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
    <?php

    // Display the 2nd image (if it exists)
    if( isset( $gallery_image_ids[1] ) ) :
        ?><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $gallery_image_ids[1], 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Related : [How to show all images in WooCommerce product description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620929/how-to-show-all-images-in-woocommerce-product-description/62624012#62624012)

Comment: Code display first photo with error: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Comment: thank you for help. now works without error but displaying first photo. how to display second one? this is the case for me.

Comment: sorry for asking again... but not working. for sure have more photos but code still display onli first photo :)

Comment: @iqique Updated a little mistake… For me the code works perfectly, it display the 1st and the 2nd gallery images (when they exist)… tested on last woocommerce version… So there is something else that is making trouble in your case.

Comment: to understund correct i want to display second photo from gallery. not display second gallery. correct?

Comment: @iqique yes it's the case… You have just to remove in my code the first one…