# remove the woocommerce slider and simply display the images (variable product)

Tags: woocommerce, slider, product-variations

I use the "WooCommerce Additional Variation Images" plugin to add additional images to my variable products.

I also use "Product Variation Swatches for WooCommerce (Pro)" to give the choice of a more aesthetic color.

Both plugins work perfectly together.

But :

I just want to display my images without the woocommerce slider.

Thank you for your help.

I tried this:

[How to show all images in WooCommerce product description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620929/how-to-show-all-images-in-woocommerce-product-description)

It works but only for simple products.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the condition to include variable products as well.

So you have to change this bit of code:

```
// Single product pages (woocommerce)
if ( is_product() ) {
```

to also include variable products:

```
// Single product and variable product pages (woocommerce)
if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
```

So the based on the provided [provided source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620929/how-to-show-all-images-in-woocommerce-product-description), you can try this:

```
// Display description tab when empty
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'display_description_product_tabs' );
    function display_description_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['description'] = array(
        'title'    => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority' => 10,
        'callback' => 'woocommerce_product_description_tab',
    );

    return $tabs;
}

// Add image to description
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_product_image_woocommerce_description' );
function add_product_image_woocommerce_description( $content ) {
    global $product;

    // Single product and variable product pages (woocommerce)
    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){

        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        // HERE your main image
        echo $product->get_image( array('700', '600'), array( "class" => "img-responsive" ), '' );

        $image_content = "";

        // Loop through gallery Image Ids
        foreach( $product->get_gallery_image_ids() as $image_id ) {

            echo '<img src="'. wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'full') . '" alt="image_content" width="500" height="600">';
        }

        echo '<p> TEST Image content </p>'; // Testing text

        // Inserting the buffered content after
        $content .= ob_get_clean();
    }

    return $content;
}
```